# Use Ansible k8s to deploy pod to AKS

Tags: azure, kubernetes, ansible, azure-aks

I have a question - is it possible to use Ansible k8s module (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/modules/k8s_module.html) in order to deploy application to AKS (Azure Kubernetes Service)? If so, how could it be done? I'm struggling with that and have no idea. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: yeah, same way you normally would. give it config to work against and create\edit objects

Comment: I did it in the same way, I am connected to my AKS cluster and run the playbook. Everything seems to be finished, but when I call kubectl get pods, my pod is not there...

Comment: what if you do `kubectl get all --all-namespace`? maybe its in a different namespace?

Comment: @4c74356b41 Thank you! That is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this case problem was due to resource being deployed to a different namespace. this is how you would find those:

```
kubectl get all --all-namespace
```